# how to read json keys with different number of objects in java

Tags: java, json

I  have a Json file that is as below:

```
{   
"fileExtension":["xls","xlsx"],
"fileType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
"fileName": "Dummy123",
"worksheetCount":"3",
"worksheetList":["ws1","ws2","ws3"],
"worksheet":
{
    "ws1":
    {
        "worksheetName":"Employee Info",
        "sectionCount":"1",
        "sectionList":["Employee"],
        "sectionName":"Employee",
        "sectionType":"table",
        "Employee":
        {
            "columnCount": "3",
            "beginningRowNumber": "2",
            "endingRowNumber": "7",
            "columnList":[
            "columns":
              {
                "c1":
                {
                    "c1_header": "EMP ID",
                    "c1_datatype" :"Numeric"
                },  
                "c2":
                {
                    "c2_header": "EMP NAME",
                    "c2_datatype" : "String"
                },
                "c3":
                {
                    "c3_header": "DESIGNATION",
                    "c3_datatype":"String"
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

here the worksheet count and section count and column count varies for each object like "`ws1`". I have many objects in my json like `ws1`. but in each of this the section count and column count varies and there are json objects for each section and each column, I want to get the value for each section and column and worksheet without repeating my code. Could someone please help me out.

Comment: what is relation between columnList and columns property?is it "columnList":["column"] and based on that list "column":{} ?

Answer (score 0):

```
JSJSONObject worksheets=rootobject.getJSONObject("worksheet");
JSONArray worksheetName=rootobject.getJSONArray("worksheetList");
int lenght=worksheetName.lenght();

for(int i=0;i<lenght;i++)
{
    JSJSONObject ws=worksheets.getJSONObject(worksheetName.getString(i));
    JSONArray sectionList=rootobject.getJSONArray("sectionList");
    for(int j=0;j<sectionList.lenght();j++)
    {
        JSJSONObject section=ws.getJSONObject(sectionList.getString(j));
        JSONArray columnList=section.getJSONArray("columnList");
        for(int k=0;k<columnList.lenght();k++)
        {
            JSJSONObject column=ws.getJSONObject(columnList.getString(k));
            JSONArray keys = column.names ();
            for (int l = 0; l < keys.length (); l++) {
                String key = keys.getString (l); // Here's your key
                JSJSONObject c1_c2_c3=column.getJSONObject(key);//c1_c2_c3 indicate c1 or c2 or c3
                JSONArray c1_c2_c3Keys = c1_c2_c3.names ();
                for (int m = 0; m < c1_c2_c3Keys.length (); m++) {
                    String c1_c2_c3key = c1_c2_c3Keys.getString (m); // Here's your key i.e. c1_header,c1_datatype,c2_header
                    String header_datatype=c1_c2_c3.getString(c1_c2_c3key);//header_datatype indicate header or datatype i.e. EMP ID ,Numeric
                }
            }
         }
    }
}
```

hope this will help you .

Comment: May I know why is JSJSONObject used In your code and not JSONObject?

Comment: while finding solution i got all required method with this package.you can use  org.json.JSONObject if you want to,i am not sure but all the methods are available there with some different or even with similar usage.you can also look into com.google.gson.JsonObject. Its up to you.